# Set the y-intercept (b) equal to 0 when creating a linear regression model in Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, linear-regression

I'm trying to replicate a linear regression model built in gSheets using the `Linest` function in Bigquery.

With Linest, one of the parameters lets you force the y-intercept to be 0. Here is the documentation:

> calculate_b - [ OPTIONAL - TRUE by default ] - Given a linear form of
> y = m*x+b, calculates the y-intercept (b) if TRUE. Otherwise, forces b
> to be 0 and only calculates the m values if FALSE, i.e. forces the
> curve fit to pass through the origin.

In Bigquery I am using the ML model feature. Eg:

```
  create or replace model dataset.name
    options(model_type = 'linear_reg', input_label_cols = ['label_dependant_var']) as

    select 
      label_dependant_var, y, z
    from data_set.source
```

This BQ script gives me different results than the gSheet Linest function. If I set the Linest calculate_b input to "TRUE", then the results match my BQ output. However, I want to set the y-intercept to equal 0 (calculate_b is FALSE). The problem is that I can't figure out how to set this on the BQ side.

Anyone know how to do this? Thank you!!

There is a "fit_intercept" option I can set on the BQ model, but setting this to TRUE or FALSE has no impact on my model's coefficients.

Comment: Could you try specifying `standardize_features=false` along with `fit_intercept=false` in the model_option_list? For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create).

Comment: @PrajnaRaiT That worked! Thank you so much! What's odd is that standardize_features is not documented in the linear_reg page

Comment: Just did! Thanks again. I have another question here you have to know this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75870647/can-the-bigquery-ml-to-run-multiple-regressions-using-a-single-model-create-repl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue can be resolved by specifying `standardize_features=false` along with `fit_intercept=false` in the model_option_list.

For more information you can refer to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create).