# Can the Bigquery ML to run multiple regressions using a single model create/replace command?

Tags: google-bigquery, linear-regression

I am using Bigquery to run a series of linear regressions, but am having trouble running multiple models in a scalable way. More specifically, I have a table with the following fields:

```
- week
- dependant variable
- independent variable a
- independent variable b
```

What I want is to perform a unique regression model for each week. Currently I am doing this with the following query:

```
create or replace model data_set.model_3_20_23
  options(model_type = 'linear_reg', input_label_cols = ['dependant_variable']) as

  select dependant variable, independent variable a, independent variable b
  from data_set.source_info
  where week = '2023-03-20'
;

create or replace model data_set.model_3_13_23
  options(model_type = 'linear_reg', input_label_cols = ['dependant_variable']) as

  select dependant variable, independent variable a, independent variable b
  from data_set.source_info
  where week = '2023-03-13'
;
```

Instead of running two separate models, I'm wondering if it is possible to combine these into a single model with a single output where week is the first column.

Let me know! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery ML currently doesn't support running multiple models using a single CREATE MODEL statement, you could try BigQuery [procedural language](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language) to execute multiple CREATE MODEL statements in one query.